# "Effective" in the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "effective" mean if used at the beginning of a sentence?

e.g. "Effective ____________________    , your child may not return to school until proof of immunizations has been sent to the school nurse."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to indicate the time from when a regulation, procedure, or arrangement starts, the verb ***effect***, or ***take effect***, in one or other of its inflected forms is frequently used. These are the usual idioms:

> ***With effect from 1st July***, there will be an increase in subscription to £10 per month
>
> *In future men will no longer be expected to wear a neck-tie, ladies will be permitted to wear trousers, and no member expected to toast
>   the monarch, in the mess room, such changes **to take effect** from
>   this coming Friday*.
>
> *The fire alarms will be tested every Thursday morning, **effective immediately***.

***Effective immediately*** can be placed at the start or later in a sentence, and is just a short form of ***it will be effective immediately***.

Comment: 'Effect' is if anything a **noun** in a larger construction (compound preposition?) in 'With effect [from]'.  As it is in 'take effect' (though I'd not analyse 'take effect', 'take place'... as other than MWVs).